# failed to connect to port 80

Tags: android, android-networking

After clicking on login button "attempting to login" message is displayed only and no further activity is there in the app and also after clicking the button an exception is displayed in LOGCAT "java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)" .May be only preexecute is running and not the background tasks.But Where is the problem ?

Login.java--->

```
public class Login extends Activity {
        AutoCompleteTextView UsernameEt;
        EditText PasswordEt;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            UsernameEt = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
            PasswordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        }

        class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

           // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/login3.php";
           // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.*.*/login3.php";
           private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/login3.php";

            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

                try {

                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("name", args[0]);
                    params.put("password", args[1]);

                    Log.d("request", "starting");

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                    if (json != null) {
                        Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                        return json;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                int success = 0;
                String message = "";

                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }

                if (json != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, json.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Success!", message);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Failure", message);
                }
            }

        }

        public void OnLogin(View view) {
            String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
            String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();

            new PostAsync().execute(username, password);

        }
    }
```

................................................................................
JsonParser.java---->

```
public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your phone's localhost port 80 or are you trying to access data from the computer the emulator is running on?

Comment: I am running it on genymotion.I have already tried  "http://10.0.3.2:8080/login3.php";..........
 "http://192.168.*.*/login3.php";.........
 "http://127.0.0.1/login3.php";

Comment: are you running Apache or something along those lines on the host PC?

Comment: What port is Apache running on?

Comment: Xampp control panel is showing port(s) 80,443 for apache

Comment: If you go to 127.0.0.1:80 in your browser, what do you see?

Comment: And what happens when you go to localhost:8080?

Comment: This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Have you configured Apache to point to the folder where the php script is?

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes i have configured it.

Comment: Apache is not serving the php file, it seems.

Comment: In my php code I added one html form to test the login.It was working fine then with html.It was running the query on mysql database and was showing the result too.But in android it is creating problem for me.